# Jquery Data Table paging issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datatables

Hello i am using Jquery data table to display a table from the server side. It was displaying on the client side but the paging buttons are all inactive. Please what am I doing wrong?

Below is me client side data table call:

```
 $('#profileList').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "/SearchProfile/MySearchProfileAjaxHandler"
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might want to do something like this instead:

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/pipeline.html

The question is how many values are sending back? Also, what kind of data are you sending back?

Comment: The size of the value sent back to the client varies according to the dataset processed on the server side. The data sent back are mainly strings.

Comment: Thanks so much Jamie the pipe-lining technique work like magic. The inactive buttons are now active and working. Thanks for the link.